# How do I amend shared data source definitions after SSRS migration to a diff node?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Do not seem to be able to find any place in the portal or Report Builder where I can actually edit the connect string & creds.

Report Manager shows the XML, but that really is it.

Disk files (from the looks of it) are no longer present in high versions (using SQL 2016/2017).

Is there a known location anywhere in GUI, or maybe direct edits in the SQL Server repository?
I can't even delete a shared source anymore, only view or test the connection.

If anybody could post a screenshot, it'll be highly appreciated.

EDIT: Just found out - when I create a new Data Source, it's editable; the imported data sources are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways of doing this. You can set the 'overwrite datasource' option in the project properties.

Or, you can got to the report portal , show hidden items in the view menu and there is a folder called "data sources". Open this and you will see all data sources, from there you can edit and save changes. All reports that use that datasource will be affected.

[image]

Comment: Fantastic, thank you Alan, you're helping people again. Method #2 worked beautifully. Last night I instead hacked the XML content definition of the catalog table, but your way was so much easier. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help. Could you please mark the answer as accepted, this way it will help others in the future